# How do I rename an open file in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to rename an open file in Emacs? While I'm viewing it? Something like save-as, but the original one should go away.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Try this function from [Steve Yegge's .emacs](http://steve.yegge.googlepages.com/my-dot-emacs-file):

```
;; source: http://steve.yegge.googlepages.com/my-dot-emacs-file
(defun rename-file-and-buffer (new-name)
  "Renames both current buffer and file it's visiting to NEW-NAME."
  (interactive "sNew name: ")
  (let ((name (buffer-name))
        (filename (buffer-file-name)))
    (if (not filename)
        (message "Buffer '%s' is not visiting a file!" name)
      (if (get-buffer new-name)
          (message "A buffer named '%s' already exists!" new-name)
        (progn
          (rename-file filename new-name 1)
          (rename-buffer new-name)
          (set-visited-file-name new-name)
          (set-buffer-modified-p nil))))))
```

Take a look at that page, there's another really useful related function there, called "move-buffer-file".

Comment: Note: this method is not compatible with `(setq uniquify-buffer-name-style 'forward)` meaning if you have buffer named `users\index.html` (because you already have another buffer for `posts\index.html`) the renaming will fail

Comment: `(set-buffer-modified-p nil)` seems unnecessary. If you called `rename-file-and-buffer` on a modified buffer and then attempted to kill it, it would happily do it without warning you about unsaved changes.

Comment: This function will also (somewhat annoyingly) ask you for a new name *before* checking whether the current buffer is associated with a file at all (in which case it aborts).

Answer (score 396):

Yes, with `dired` mode, you can:

- `C-x d` to open dired
- `RET` to select directory of current file
- `C-x C-j` (`dired-jump` to the name of the current file, in Dired)
- `R` to rename the file (or `dired-do-rename`).
- `q` to go back to the (renamed) file buffer

The rename is equivalent to a shell `mv`, but it will also update any open buffers, and unlike `mv` it will not change the access and modify times on the file in the filesystem.

Comment: That's not directly renaming the current file.

Comment: C-x b and you're back in the original buffer. You could write an Elisp function to do it, but I doubt you'll save many keystrokes with it.

Comment: Also, rather than C-x b, you can press C-x k to be back in the original buffer.

Comment: As to how to skip searching for the file from the dired buffer, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933484/open-dired-and-select-the-file-associated-with-the-previous-buffer

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It's simpler than adding functions. As for "That's not directly renaming the current file", it seems to do just that. The file is renamed on the disk and the buffer.

Comment: The `C-x C-j` is not bound by default for me. Doing `M-x load-library RET dired-x RET` first makes it bound.

Comment: To me this is the best answer as the concept of "direct" action becomes quite fuzzy when we're talking of a few keystrokes. Usually `quit-window` is bound to `q` so it's just a matter of `C-x C-j R [filename] RET q`. How "indirect" is this in practice?

Comment: Another alternative if `C-x C-j` is unbound is just do `M-x dired-jump` on the first time. It will automatically load `dired-x` (which will also cause `C-x C-j` to be defined from this point on).

Comment: Completing the `dired-do-rename` step certainly renames the file.  I am not sure what @pupeno is objecting to.

Comment: I did not have to do the `C-x C-j` at all.  `dired` brought me to the name of the current file and `R` let me rename it.  I suspect `emacs` has made that more convenient in modern versions.

Answer (score 132):

Just for completeness, since some folks may visit this page thinking they will get an answer for the "save as" feature of Emacs, that's C-x C-w for an open file.

Comment: C-x C-w or use the menu `File > Save as...`

Comment: Not quite "save as", since the file you are editing will still be the original one.

Comment: @asmeurer You are wrong! After saving, you will be editing the new file.

Comment: Again, why isn't there a feature to downvote comments?!

Comment: Perhaps asmeurer meant, "the file you [were] editing will still [exist]". Then, is that correct? I would check, but then, you cannot downvote my comment, hahaha.

Comment: And then to erase the old one?

Comment: Save as is nothing to do with rename.

Answer (score 33):

My favorite is the one from Magnars (of [emacs rocks screencasts](http://emacsrocks.com) fame.)

Unlike the other alternatives, you don't have to type the name out from scratch - you get the current name to modify.

```
(defun rename-current-buffer-file ()
  "Renames current buffer and file it is visiting."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((name (buffer-name))
        (filename (buffer-file-name))
        (basename (file-name-nondirectory filename)))
    (if (not (and filename (file-exists-p filename)))
        (error "Buffer '%s' is not visiting a file!" name)
      (let ((new-name (read-file-name "New name: " (file-name-directory filename) basename nil basename)))
        (if (get-buffer new-name)
            (error "A buffer named '%s' already exists!" new-name)
          (rename-file filename new-name 1)
          (rename-buffer new-name)
          (set-visited-file-name new-name)
          (set-buffer-modified-p nil)
          (message "File '%s' successfully renamed to '%s'"
                   name (file-name-nondirectory new-name)))))))
```

Thanks to James Yang for a correct version.

Comment: This is NOT working properly. This one adds a "/" at the end of file.

Comment: Thanks for posting that out for me. The SO way is to correct answers, not post new, slightly modified ones.

Answer (score 15):

Here's a more robust version adapted from stevey.

```
;; Originally from stevey, adapted to support moving to a new directory.
(defun rename-file-and-buffer (new-name)
  "Renames both current buffer and file it's visiting to NEW-NAME."
  (interactive
   (progn
     (if (not (buffer-file-name))
         (error "Buffer '%s' is not visiting a file!" (buffer-name)))
     ;; Disable ido auto merge since it too frequently jumps back to the original
     ;; file name if you pause while typing. Reenable with C-z C-z in the prompt.
     (let ((ido-auto-merge-work-directories-length -1))
       (list (read-file-name (format "Rename %s to: " (file-name-nondirectory
                                                       (buffer-file-name))))))))
  (if (equal new-name "")
      (error "Aborted rename"))
  (setq new-name (if (file-directory-p new-name)
                     (expand-file-name (file-name-nondirectory
                                        (buffer-file-name))
                                       new-name)
                   (expand-file-name new-name)))
  ;; Only rename if the file was saved before. Update the
  ;; buffer name and visited file in all cases.
  (if (file-exists-p (buffer-file-name))
      (rename-file (buffer-file-name) new-name 1))
  (let ((was-modified (buffer-modified-p)))
    ;; This also renames the buffer, and works with uniquify
    (set-visited-file-name new-name)
    (if was-modified
        (save-buffer)
      ;; Clear buffer-modified flag caused by set-visited-file-name
      (set-buffer-modified-p nil)))

  (setq default-directory (file-name-directory new-name))

  (message "Renamed to %s." new-name))
```

Comment: Nice one. Now chilling in my functions.el.

Answer (score 13):

Here's another version, that's pretty robust and VC aware:

```
(defun rename-file-and-buffer ()
  "Rename the current buffer and file it is visiting."
  (interactive)
  (let ((filename (buffer-file-name)))
    (if (not (and filename (file-exists-p filename)))
        (message "Buffer is not visiting a file!")
      (let ((new-name (read-file-name "New name: " filename)))
        (cond
         ((vc-backend filename) (vc-rename-file filename new-name))
         (t
          (rename-file filename new-name t)
          (set-visited-file-name new-name t t)))))))
```

You can read more about it [here](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/05/04/rename-file-and-buffer/).

Answer (score 11):

If you're using [Spacemacs](http://spacemacs.org/) then you get this behavior for free since it comes with an implementation of `rename-current-buffer-file` (based on magnars) that by default bound to `SPC-f-R`.

https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/bd7ef98e4c35fd87538dd2a81356cc83f5fd02f3/layers/%2Bdistributions/spacemacs-base/funcs.el#L294

Comment: I've just tested this in Doom Emacs (v27.1) and it works as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

There is a way very easy, you press the command **M-x** and than type **vc-rename-file**, after that you just need to select your current file at the directory, and than choose the new name. The buff that has the changed file will be refreshed.

**Source:**https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/VC-Delete_002fRename.html

Comment: This has the (not necessarily desirable) side effect of adding the old and new files to be committed into version control. But +1 because it uses a builtin function to (mostly) answer the OP's question.

Comment: Works even today with GNU Emacs 25.3.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9)

Comment: Got this when I used `vc-rename-file` please update files before moving them`

Comment: Indeed, it's a neat solution but it doesn't always allow you to do the renaming.

Answer (score 6):

Emacs 26.3 (2020-04-03) has `rename-file` function which can be invoked using `M-x rename-file` for renaming the current file or any other file for that matter.

Comment: In Emacs 25 this will not change the name of the file that is in buffer, i.e. the next write will go to the old-filename again.

Comment: In `emacs 27`. I did this but it just acted as `save as`

Answer (score 6):

Emacs 29.1 added `rename-visited-file` command which does exactly this, without a key binding though.

From its [NEWS](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/03914e565f75667dfce439e6d6848990aea04664/etc/NEWS.29#L732):

> ** New command 'rename-visited-file'.
> This command renames the file visited by the current buffer by moving
> it to a new name or location, and also makes the buffer visit this new
> file.

Comment: This is the cleanest way and best answer!

Answer (score 5):

based on magnars version, I modified as below, fixed the INIT file name part:

```
(defun rename-current-buffer-file ()
  "Renames current buffer and file it is visiting."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((name (buffer-name))
        (filename (buffer-file-name))
        (basename (file-name-nondirectory filename)))
    (if (not (and filename (file-exists-p filename)))
        (error "Buffer '%s' is not visiting a file!" name)
      (let ((new-name (read-file-name "New name: " (file-name-directory filename) basename nil basename)))
        (if (get-buffer new-name)
            (error "A buffer named '%s' already exists!" new-name)
          (rename-file filename new-name 1)
          (rename-buffer new-name)
          (set-visited-file-name new-name)
          (set-buffer-modified-p nil)
          (message "File '%s' successfully renamed to '%s'"
                   name (file-name-nondirectory new-name)))))))
```

Comment: This one is better. The magnars version given above is NOT working properly. Add a "/" character at the end

Answer (score 5):

The excellent `crux` [package](https://github.com/bbatsov/crux) has `crux-rename-file-and-buffer` (along with many other useful functions).

Answer (score 3):

I know the post is sooo old but in all the answer I have found, nothing is more simple that what said Emacs in their tutorial: 
`M-x Dired` (launch dired) 
`C-x C-q` (toggle read only in dired) 
change the filename like if it was just a line in a text file: 
prev:

```
  /home/okiw4n/Documents/project/light_script:
  total used in directory 20 available 339.2 GiB
  drwxr-xr-x. 2 okiw4n okiw4n 4096 Sep  7 09:07 .
  drwxr-xr-x. 3 okiw4n okiw4n 4096 Sep  4 10:03 ..
  -rw-r--r--. 1 okiw4n okiw4n 3594 Sep  7 08:39 explication.org
  -rw-r--r--. 1 okiw4n okiw4n   85 Sep  4 10:09 script.sh
  -rw-r--r--. 1 okiw4n okiw4n 3594 Sep  5 20:08 tuc.org~
```

after:

```
  /home/okiw4n/Documents/project/light_script:
  total used in directory 20 available 339.2 GiB
  drwxr-xr-x. 2 okiw4n okiw4n 4096 Sep  7 09:07 .
  drwxr-xr-x. 3 okiw4n okiw4n 4096 Sep  4 10:03 ..
  -rw-r--r--. 1 okiw4n okiw4n 3594 Sep  7 08:39 explication.org
  -rw-r--r--. 1 okiw4n okiw4n   85 Sep  4 10:09 script.sh
  -rw-r--r--. 1 okiw4n okiw4n 3594 Sep  5 20:08 TRUC.org~ (I have rewrite this file)
```

`C-x C-s` (for save the changes) 
`C-x C-k` (kill the buffer and return to the file).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any of the proposed solutions sufficient for my needs (buffer selection, overwrite confirmation, fast response, actually working etc.), here's what I'm using:

```
(defun rename-buffer-and-file (buffer newname)
  (interactive "bRename buffer and its visiting file: \nFNew name: ")
  (let ((oldname (buffer-file-name)))
    (if (not oldname)
        (message "Buffer '%s' is not visiting a file" buffer)
      (if (file-exists-p newname)
          (if (file-directory-p newname)
              ;; Signal an error if the user specified the name of an
              ;; existing directory.
              (error "%s is a directory" newname)
            (unless (y-or-n-p (format-message
                               "File `%s' exists; overwrite? "
                               newname))
              (error "Canceled"))))
      ;; Rename buffer and its visiting file
      (set-visited-file-name newname)
      ;; Delete old file
      (delete-file oldname)
      (save-buffer))))
```

bound to `C-x C-r` for convenience with

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-r") 'rename-buffer-and-file)
```

Answer (score -2):

It can be achieved by copy. shift+c on the file and emacs will ask you to denote a name for the path including the file name, so you just provide the new name,and enter...of course, you have to Delete the former one.

Comment: You seem to be referring to "C" in the dired mode? That's copying the file, not renaming it, which (as @ChrisConway noted) in dired is done with "R". And besides, OP asked for a rename of the current buffer.