# Open dired and select the file associated with the previous buffer?

Tags: emacs, elisp, rename, dired

Let's say I am editing `blah.txt` with Emacs and I decide to [open dired to rename the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384284/can-i-rename-an-open-file-in-emacs/384612#384612) blah.txt. When I press `C-x d RET` (or `C-x C-f RET`), a dired buffer will show up to display the content of the directory containing `blah.txt`, but the cursor will not be on `blah.txt`. So I need to search my file first (`C-s blah.txt`) to place my cursor on it and then I can rename it (`R`).

How do I automate or remove the step `C-s blah.txt`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`dired-jump` is exactly what you want.

```
(autoload 'dired-jump "dired-x" "Jump to dired corresponding current buffer.")
(autoload 'dired-jump-other-window "dired-x" "jump to dired in other window.")
```

Then call:

```
M-x dired-jump
```

or

```
M-x dired-jump-other-window
```

Comment: If you follow the instructions in the manual, you'll get the correct key bindings as well: `C-h i g` `(dired-x) Optional Installation Dired Jump` `RET`

Answer (score 5):

You want `C-x C-j`.

Comment: And what is `C-x C-j`?  It's not bound in text buffers or dired buffers (Emacs 23.2).

Comment: @Trey: `C-x C-j` is bound to `dired-jump`, but only when `dired-x` is loaded. (I think there's an Emacs policy that `dired-x` doesn't comply with here.)

Comment: Thanks, Gilles; I hadn't realized that it wasn't bound by default.

Answer (score 2):

[Sunrise Commander](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-jp/Sunrise_Commander)  is a much improved dired. and it does what you need by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that:

```
M-: (dired (buffer-name (current-buffer)))
```

Then the only file visible in dired will be your current file and cursor will be right on it.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of advice will do what you want:

```
(defadvice dired (around dired-jump-to-buffer activate)
  "When running dired, move cursor to the line for the buffer we came from"
  (interactive (list nil nil)) ;; bogus values, will be overwritten below
  (let ((coming-from (buffer-file-name)))
(ad-set-args 0 (dired-read-dir-and-switches ""))
ad-do-it
(when (and coming-from
       (equal (file-truename default-directory) (file-truename (file-name-directory coming-from))))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (search-forward (file-name-nondirectory coming-from) nil t))))
```

Note: Works for <kbd>C-x d</kbd>, but not the <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> entry point to dired.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ emacs --version
GNU Emacs 24.3.1
```

In .emacs:

```
(require 'dired-x)
```

Now `C-x C-j` should be bound to `dired-jump`.