# How to change the C:\ and E:\ directory in Emacs on Windows?

Tags: windows, emacs

I can change every file or directory under the same C:\ or E:.

But I find I cannot change the file C:/User/**/myfile.cpp to E:/code/yourfile.cpp.

How can I change the file buffer between C: and E: on Windows?

Comment: What problem are you having exactly?  I just tried opening and saving files across drives on an unmodified Emacs install, and I didn't have any problem.  As an aside, I have a suspicion that your question is off-topic for Stackoverflow, and you may want to move it to [the Emacs stackexchange](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/) or to [Superuser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: `But if I find I cannot change . . .` does not convey anything meaningful because it is not proper English -- consider better explaining what that sentence fragment is supposed to mean.  For example, does that mean you have an open file-visiting buffer and you want to rename/move it from c:/myfile.cpp to e:/myfile.cpp?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I rename an open file in Emacs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384284/how-do-i-rename-an-open-file-in-emacs)  I use a modified version of one of the answers in the aforementioned thread, and I just tested it on a current version of Emacs trunk master branch built on Windows 32-bit with MinGW and ezwinports -- I had no problems renaming an open file-visiting buffer to a different drive.

Comment: Sorry for all, English is my second language, so there may be some errors. What I exactly mean is, When I start my Emacs, I'm in C:/User/**/ ( ~/ ), But I cannot visit a file in E:/myfile.txt.

Comment: Does this work?:  `M-x find-file RET E:/myfile.txt RET`